# Publishing Earth Engine App with restricted access

Tags: google-earth-engine, publishing

I am having trouble publishing Earth Engine Apps with restricted access.

The simple test app [here](https://rsac_tim.users.earthengine.app/view/restrictedapptest) works as expected when publicly accessible. However, if access is restricted to the membership of a Google Group, the link won’t load; instead it constantly tries to redirect to an address like:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https://rsac_tim.users.earthengine.app/view/restrictedapptest&ust=1591356256714732&usg=AFQjCNGAQ7Gmk154EYzVPkM8m1WqC98FMg (in each loop the `ust` and `usg` values are different)

All that appears on the page is the message:

> Redirecting you to https://rsac_tim.users.earthengine.app/view/restrictedapptest.

This is the case in both Firefox and Chrome. The GEE source code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6b2575ec3d86402b2c7c0575b8a5415d). The Google Group specified is owned by me (same account used to create the GEE script).

Have others experienced this? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, restricted apps cannot be accessed if the publisher has an underscore in their Earth Engine username (such as `rsac_tim`).

Unfortunately, the only available workaround at this time is to publish the app as another user.